# How can I install the development version of Node?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, nodejs

I want to get the latest updates for [Node](https://github.com/joyent/node) (evented I/O for v8 javascript).

I already have installed `Node` using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

How can I get the latest updates? Maybe using a PPA for development version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the stable node.js PPA; for the development version you'll want to use this PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js-devel

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js-devel -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

You'll also likely want to remove the first PPA you added:

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed/310#310)

Comment: This worked very good. I have now `v0.11.11`.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

After add repository:

```
sudo apt-get update      
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```